# JS GetElementByClassName[0] return undefined

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am following a tutorial on W3Schools to make a JS slideshow. While this seems simple enough, even after directly copying their code, my JavaScript is having some VERY nonsensical and frustrating errors. The issue seems to be that, when my function accesses `document.getElementsByClassName("slides")[some_index_here]`, it returns undefined, despite that, when I access the SAME element in the exact same way through inspect element console, what I am looking for shows up. What is going on?

Comment: Are you declaring your script after the DOM or before it? My assumption is your script is loading before it has time to parse over the DOM.

Comment: We need your markup

Comment: Your code is being executed before those elements exist on the page

Comment: this is nonsensical and silly :-) we should write a letter to w3 schools

Comment: "I am following a tutorial on W3Schools" Thank You for not linking to *that* site.  ;)

Comment: If figured out that I was not wrapping anything in window.onload.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I needed to wrap what I did in a `window.onload` function, because the code was executing before elements existed.